# Need help with the sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, conditionals

I would like to ask which one of the following sentences are grammatically correct? And any suggestions for similar context would be greatly appreciated.

> Without WikiLeaks or Julian Assange, the crimes of the empire would have been called just another 'Conspiracy theories'.

OR

> Had there been no WikiLeaks or Julian Assange, the crimes of the empire would have been called just another 'Conspiracy theories'.

Best Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither are correct because 'another' requires a singular word. It should be 'conspiracy theory' not 'conspiracy theories'.

Without... sounds better than "Had there been no."

But even better would be: "Had it not been for WikiLeaks or Julian Assange..."